# Looping through an array of objects in quiz app

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, dom

I created a quiz app and had some issues luckily I solved the problem but I am just curious. So the issue was I had an array which contains questions and answers. I wanted to loop through the array and display next question when I click the next button. The problem is when I clicked the next button nothing happened only the last question was displayed

Here is a sample code

```
const questions = [

{
question: "What is 2 + 2?",
answers: [3,4,5,6]
},
{
question: "What is 6 + 2?",
answers: [9,8,5,6]

},
{
question: "What is 10 + 30?",
answers: [32,45,40,34]

}

]

const p = document.getElementById("qtn");
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",()=> {

for (let i=0; i<questions.length;i++){

p.textContent = questions[i].question;
}

});
```

But when I removed the for loop it worked

```
const i=0;
const p = document.getElementById("qtn");
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",()=> {



p.textContent = questions[i].question;
i++

});
```

So why did the second solution work but not the first one

Comment: *"...only the first question was displayed"* - Are you sure you don't mean the *last* question? The loop in the first example is not necessary. With each click, it sets the text to *all of the questions one-after-another*. The very last one will always be the one displayed because it's last in the loop. Check out the console in [**this example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fq432bzg/) for a more clear demonstration.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant the last question. I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in your first solution the only answer that was displayed was the last one.

The reason why that happened is because the result of the `for` loop was always the same. It had no purpose whatsoever.

Each time you pressed next, the `for` loop would run from `i = 0` until `questions.length`. This means that it runs until the end of the loop, changing the value of `p.textContent` very quickly on each iteration of the loop. Therefore, the only result you would see is the last message (after the loop ends).

When you removed the loop, your code just increments after each click, therefore displaying the desired result. Also for counter I would use `let i= 0;` instead of `const`.

Hope it clarified things out for you.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify so I cannot use foreach, for(..of) etc. also?

Comment: I mean, It doesn't make sense to use in this case, because you need one iteration at a time

Answer (score 0):

you can not update value to `const` if it is not array or object , use `var` or `let` instead.

```js
const questions = [
{
question: "What is 2 + 2?",
answes: [3,4,5,6]
},
{
question: "What is 6 + 2?",
answes: [9,8,5,6]

},
{
question: "What is 10 + 30?",
answes: [32,45,40,34]
}
];

var p = document.getElementById("qtn");
var current=0;
var questionIndex=current+1;

p.innerHTML = '('+ questionIndex +')  '+questions[current].question;

var prevButton=document.getElementById("prev");
var nextButton=document.getElementById("next");

function nextQuestion(){

if(current<questions.length-1){
current++;
questionIndex=current+1;
p.innerHTML = '('+ questionIndex +')  '+questions[current].question;
prevButton.style.display="block";
}

if(current===questions.length-1){
prevButton.style.display="block"
nextButton.style.display = "none";
}

}


function prevQuestion(){
if(current>0){
current--;
questionIndex=questionIndex-1;
p.innerHTML = '('+ questionIndex +')  '+questions[current].question;
nextButton.style.display="block";
}

if(current===0){
prevButton.style.display="none"
nextButton.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

```html
<p id="qtn"></p>
<button id="prev" style="display:none" onclick="prevQuestion()">Prev</button>
<button id="next" style="display:block" onclick="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
```